# How to fix a dynamic route

Tags: java, vuejs3

I'm just taking a vue3 project and need a bit of help with a dynamic route.

Firstly, I have a pet.json archive where I have information about dogs and cats. I'm gonna show you my project:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-header />
    <div class="app-container">
      <router-link to="{ id: PetDetail, params: { id: json.id, pet:pet }}"
        ><router-view
      /></router-link>
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AppHeader from "@/components/AppHeader.vue";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    AppHeader,
    Footer,
  },
};
</script>
```

route.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import Home from "@/views/Home.vue";
import NotFound from "@/views/NotFound.vue";
import PetDetail from "@/components/PetDetail.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },

  {
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)",
    name: "NotFound",
    component: NotFound,
  },

  {
    path: "/pet/:id?",
    name: "PetDetail",
    component: PetDetail,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

PetDetail.vue

```
<template>
  <header id="header" class="header">
    <div class="header-container_pet container">
      <nav>
        <a class="btn-icon logo-btn" href="/">
          <img
            class="logo logo-normal"
            src="../assets/logo_white.svg"
            alt="Logo petinder"
          />
          <img
            class="logo logo-white"
            src="../assets/logo.svg"
            alt="Logo petinder"
          />
        </a>
        <ul class="menu-links">
          <li><a href="">Servicios</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contactar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <a href="" class="btn btn-login btn-light" title="Iniciar sesión"
        >Iniciar sesión</a
      >

      <div id="menuIcon" class="menu-icon">
        <div id="menuIconBar" class="menu-icon-bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="page-home">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block-featured-content">
        <div class="foto-pet">
          <div class="foto-pet-color"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pet-info">
          <p class="pet-title">
            Darko <span class="blue-text">5 años, Barcelona</span>
          </p>
          <div class="pet-details">
            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Especie</span>
              <span class="pet-detail-data">Perro</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Sexo</span>
              <span class="pet-detail-data">Macho</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Medida</span>
              <span class="pet-detail-data">Pequeño</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Fecha de nacimiento</span>
              <span class="pet-detail-data">08/10/2016</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Estado</span>
              <span class="pet-detail-data">En adopción</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="buttom">
            <div class="buttom-adoptar">
              <p class="p-adoptar-text">Lo quiero adoptar</p>
            </div>
            <div class="buttom-compartir">
              <p class="p-compartir-text">Compartir</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pet-history">
        <h3 class="my-history">Mi historia</h3>
        <p class="my-history-text">
          Darko a sus 5 años de edad tiene que volver a buscar un hogar, su
          dueña ingresaba y nadie se podía hacer cargo de él. Como buen Bulldog
          Francés es muy bueno, cariñoso y sociable, pero a la vez cabezota y
          obstinado, ideal para amantes de esta raza. Esperamos que Darko no
          tenga que pasar mucho más tiempo en una jaula y por fin, encuentre esa
          familia que lo cuide y quiera como se merece.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="pet-extras">
        <div class="pet-extra">
          <h3 class="my-history">Mi personalidad</h3>
          <div class="tags">
            <span class="tag-blue">Bueno con otros perros</span>
            <span class="tag-blue">Cariñoso</span>
            <span class="tag-blue">A veces ladro</span>
            <span class="tag-blue">Amigable con extraños</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pet-extra">
          <h3 class="my-history">Me entregan</h3>
          <div class="pet-details-extra">
            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Vacunado</span>
              <span class="tag-red">No</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Desparasitado</span>
              <span class="tag-green">Si</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Esterilizado</span>
              <span class="tag-green">Si</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Microchip</span>
              <span class="tag-green">Si</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pet-extra">
          <h3 class="my-history">Tienes que saber</h3>
          <div class="pet-details-extra">
            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-data">Estoy en tratamiento médico</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-data">Soy positivo en Leishmania</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <section class="block-actions">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="match-box">
          <p class="match-text">
            Si <b>Darko</b> ya ha sido adoptado/a o no hacéis match, tenemos
            otros animales que te necesitan. Encuéntralos
          </p>
          <form class="search-bar">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Busca a tu nuevo mejor amigo"
              class="form-control search-control"
            />
            <button type="submit" class="btn-icon search-button"></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</template>
<script>
import json from "@/pets.json";
export default {
  name: "PetDetail",
  data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      object: {},
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.object = json.objects.find((item) => item.id == this.$route.params.id);
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

PetList.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="title">Últimas incorporaciones</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div
        class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"
        v-for="pet in pets"
        :key="pet.name"
      >
        <article class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <img
              class="card-img-top"
              :src="pet.image_url"
              alt="{{ pet.name }}"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-main">
              <!-- <h3 class="card-title">{{ pet.nom }}</h3> -->
              <h3 class="card-title">{{ pet.name }}</h3>
              <p class="card-text">{{ pet.location }}</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="card-icons">
              <li>
                <img
                  v-if="pet.species == 'Gato'"
                  class="card-icon"
                  src="../assets/icons/icon_cat.svg"
                  alt="{{ pet.species }}"
                />
                <img
                  v-if="pet.species == 'Perro'"
                  class="card-icon"
                  src="../assets/icons/icon_dog.svg"
                  alt="{{ pet.species }}"
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img
                  v-if="pet.sex == 'Macho'"
                  class="card-icon"
                  src="../assets/icons/icon_male.svg"
                  alt="{{ pet.sex }}"
                />
                <img
                  v-if="pet.sex == 'Hembra'"
                  class="card-icon"
                  src="../assets/icons/icon_female.svg"
                  alt="{{ pet.sex }}"
                />
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import json from "@/pets.json";
export default {
  name: "PetList",
  data() {
    return {
      pets: json.data,
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

pet.json

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Thor",
            "image_url": "https://petinder-images.netlify.app/thor.png",
            "location": "Barcelona",
            "species": "Gato",
            "sex": "Macho",
            "size": "Mediano",
            "birth_date": "2018-06-01",
            "handle_status": {
                "vaccinated": false,
                "dewormed": true,
                "sterilized": true,
                "microchip": true
            },
            "bio": "Thor llegó de Montcada y es algo tímido pero con un poco de confianza se deja mimar y acariciar.",
            "status": "En adopción",
            "personality": [
                "Bueno con gatos",
                "Timido",
                "Juguetón"
            ],
            "info_notes": []
        },
```

PetList.vue prints all pet cards in home page. And I need click on each pet to go to their card using his id.

I don't know where is my problem but for sure I'm not calling good the route link.